# Designing waveguide based structure using cst

Tags: design, waveguide

I am going to start designing waveguide based circulator , hybrid and loads using cst or ansys workbench. 
I am quite familiar with the design of microstripline and stripline based systems using ADS. 
But I am.new at designing using waveguide based structures..I want to know how should I start. I am familiar with the theory of waveguides.but I don't know how to design waveguide based structure..Like how to launch the RF power, how to design cavity , how to couple energy , how to realize diffrent modes in waveguides. 
Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Read the manufacturer documentation for CST and follow some of their help examples, come back with more specific questions, read the literature on microwave cavities.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply.. I had a glimpse over the manufacturers documentation. And it helped me.to. some extent..But being specific I'm trying to design waveguide circulator using ferrite. How should I start designing ? I mean , I want to start from scratch.